# 3D surface plot from csv data

Tags: 3d, csv

I am trying to plot velocity data from a probe measured across a channel.

The goal is a surface spanned over the measured points and colored according to the velocity value (v) and viewed from the top (like a "colormap"?). Including shading between those points. The best result, after a day of trying I, was able to come up with is listed below. The shading between the points is still missing.

When replacing the parameters for `addplot3` to `surf` it gets worse.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, filecontents}


\begin{filecontents*}{04_v_plot.csv}
depth,column,v
0.05,0.025,3.797153190429337
0.1,0.025,3.726861900740809
0.15,0.025,3.5359111045962095
0.2,0.025,3.4128410835129053
0.25,0.025,3.140235925631795
0.05,0.1,4.243357377017983
0.1,0.1,4.1459069835908196
0.15,0.1,3.9166226281025893
0.2,0.1,4.106142900384007
0.25,0.1,3.4708819672783275
0.05,0.175,4.132121899523459
0.1,0.175,3.768785853709482
0.15,0.175,3.345251163711442
0.2,0.175,3.2543256435843415
0.25,0.175,2.7823975289356344
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xlabel={Horizontal position},
      ylabel={Depth},
      colorbar,
      y dir=reverse,
      ymin=0,
      ymax=0.3,
      xmin=0,
      xmax=0.2,
      view={0}{90},
      ]

      \addplot3+[scatter, only marks] table[x=column,y=depth,z=v,col sep=comma]{04_v_plot.csv};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Velocities at positions}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I rearranged the data from the original csv:

```
depth,A,B,C
0.05,3.797153190429337,4.243357377017983,4.132121899523459
0.1,3.726861900740809,4.1459069835908196,3.768785853709482
0.15,3.5359111045962095,3.9166226281025893,3.345251163711442
0.2,3.4128410835129053,4.106142900384007,3.2543256435843415
0.25,3.140235925631795,3.4708819672783275,2.7823975289356344
```

Would it be possible to read the original csv file and plot the data?

Answer (score 1):

[`Asymptote`](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net) solution:

```
// csv-colormap.asy
//
// run  
//    asy csv-colormap.asy
//
// to get a standalone image in csv-colormap.pdf
//
settings.tex="pdflatex";
size(12cm,12cm);
import graph;
import palette;
import colorbrewer;
import fontsize;defaultpen(fontsize(8pt));
texpreamble("\usepackage{lmodern}"+"\usepackage{amsmath}"
            +"\usepackage{amsfonts}"+"\usepackage{amssymb}");
file fin=input("04_v_plot.csv").csv();
string[] s=fin.line(); // skip the title line
real[][] A=fin;
A=transpose(A);
real[] x=A[0];
real[] y=A[1];
real[] z=A[2];

pen[] Palette=Blues9;

picture bar;
bounds range=image(x,y,z,Palette);

palette(bar,rotate(90)*"Velocity",range,(0,0),(0.5cm,5.3cm)
          ,Right,Palette,PaletteTicks("$%+#.1f$"));
add(bar.fit(),point(E),30E);

xaxis("Horizontal position",BottomTop,LeftTicks(Step=0.05,step=0.01),above=true);
yaxis("Depth",LeftRight,RightTicks(Step=0.05,step=0.01),above=true);
```

[image]

Note, that this code uses a palette `Blues9` from
[colorbrewer.asy](https://github.com/blatts/asy-colorbrewer),
which provides
[Prof. Cynthia Brewer's color schemes](http://colorbrewer2.org)
as pen arrays for asymptote.
Of course, it can be replaced with any other suitable palette.